# How can I change a theme for a specific module?

Tags: 7, theme-negotiation

I am new to Drupal, I want to change a theme for a particular module (private message module) current look and feel is not pretty.

I am planning to put a "Garland" theme for Private message module. I have two development environments dev1 & dev2. I have installed private message module in both Environments with different themes Dev1 have "Seven" and Dev2 have "Garland" theme.

Is it possible to set in dev1 with private message module theme as "Garland" and remaining all can use "Seven" theme?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's no such concept as "a theme for a particular module": modules generate and manipulate content, working together to build the different parts of a page. Then a single theme renders that content to produce the HTML you see in the browser.

Your best bet would be to identify the paths of pages which you want to use a different theme for, and use something like the [Theme Key](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey) module to manage the switching for you.

Comment: Hi Clive, Thankyou for Suggestion for Theme Key module. Could you please help me to select the "Property" option to set garland theme in this path http://development1234.dd:8083/?q=messages.